Can I use inheritance with Widget or StaticConfiguration?
Is it possible to somehow use inheritance with widgets in WidgetKit? I have several widgets that share similar lines of code. How can I create, for example, a generic "circular widget" type with a certain static configuration that I can reuse and further specify across all of my circular widgets?
I tried to create a CircularWidget struct:
struct CircularWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let provider: any TimelineProvider
    let view: any View
    let families = [WidgetFamily.accessoryCircular]

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: provider) { entry in
            // WatchOS 10+
            if #available(watchOS 10.0, *) {  
                view
                    .containerBackground(.background, for: .widget)
            } 

            // Before watchOS 10
            else {  
                view
                    .padding()
                    .background()
            }
        }
        .configurationDisplayName(name)
        .description(description)
        .supportedFamilies(families)
    }
}

But it seems to require that I set values for kind, name, description, etc., rather than leaving them undefined. Also, it's saying that any View cannot conform to View on protocol with generics. I'm not sure how I can leave the view undefined.

With structs, you probably want to be looking into composition, not inheritance.

As jnpdx implied in their comment, structs don't allow inheritance. You can get much the same benefit with protocol conformance and composition however.
You said "... it seems to require that I set values for kind, name, description, etc., rather than leaving them undefined."
Sure. If you define non-optional properties in a struct (or a class for that matter) then you need to provide an initializer that gives values for those properties.
I suggest reading this article: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/composition-inheritance-code-architecture/
